# device freezes while deleting a file

Tags: android

i am trying to delete all the .apk files . this works fine! however, it makes my device dramatically slow and everything freezes for a moment. sometimes it just goes out of memory. how do i make this simple process less costly?

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // getting SDcard root path
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath());
    walkdir(dir);
}

public void walkdir(File dir) {
    String Patternjpg = ".apk";
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                walkdir(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(Patternjpg)) {
                    // Do what ever u want
                    listFile[i].delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

well i have 3 gigs of RAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this statement in a background `Thread` or an `AsnycTask`'s `doInBackground` method

```
walkdir(dir);
```

**Edit1**:
[LinkOne](http://codetheory.in/android-asynctask/)
[LinkTwo](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html#.VvjMxHr34qI)

**Edit2:**

This is one of the AsyncTask in my project. You should customize according to your requirements if needed!!

```
class ExplorerDBOperation extends AsyncTask<Void,Boolean,Boolean>{
     ProgressDialog dialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(HomeActivity.this, "Please wait", "Processing.........");
        }
@Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
String Patternjpg = ".apk";
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                walkdir(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(Patternjpg)) {
                    // Do what ever u want
                    listFile[i].delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
 return true;
}
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
            if(dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing())
            {dialog.dismiss();}


        }
}
```

In your onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// at the end of oncreate 
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ExplorerDBOperation().execute();
            }
        }, 300);

}
```

Comment: also. can it detect when task completes?

Comment: hey i am unable to call the method from asynctask maybe because its a class method and non static. can you provide a snippet?

Comment: create a class which extends AsyncTask as shown in the example links and dont make it static. Just call the class name().execute with required parameters

Comment: can you provide a snippet? because i have tried already and it says cannot make a reference

Comment: "}, 300);" is the delay before starting the method?